# How to make modal box responsive?

Tags: jquery, css, html, responsive-design, modal-dialog

I have implemented this jQuery-based modal box: http://leanmodal.finelysliced.com.au/. It works perfect, and it is quite easy to use. However, it is not responsive - contrary to the rest of the website. Here is what I got so far:

**CSS-part**

```
#lean_overlay {
    position: fixed;
    z-index:100;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: #000;
    display: none;
}
div.modalbox {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding : 10px;
    width: 400px;
    display : none;
    position : absolute;
}
.modalbox-header {
    background: url("../images/hd-bg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    border-bottom: 1px solid #CCCCCC;
    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px 0 0px 20px;
    margin: -10px 0 10px -10px;
    width : 100%;
}
```

**Javascript (part of it):**

```
(function($){$.fn.extend({leanModal:function(options){var defaults={top:100,overlay:0.5,closeButton:null};var overlay=$("<div id='lean_overlay'></div>");$("body").append(overlay);options=$.extend(defaults,options);return this.each(function(){var o=options;$(this).click(function(e){var modal_id=$(this).attr("href");$("#lean_overlay").click(function(){close_modal(modal_id)});$(o.closeButton).click(function(){close_modal(modal_id)});var modal_height=$(modal_id).outerHeight();var modal_width=$(modal_id).outerWidth();
$("#lean_overlay").css({"display":"block",opacity:0});$("#lean_overlay").fadeTo(200,o.overlay);$(modal_id).css({"display":"block","position":"fixed","opacity":0,"z-index":11000,"left":50+"%","margin-left":-(modal_width/2)+"px","top":o.top+"px"});$(modal_id).fadeTo(200,1);e.preventDefault()})});function close_modal(modal_id){$("#lean_overlay").fadeOut(200);$(modal_id).css({"display":"none"})}}})})(jQuery);
```

And, at last - **how it is used**:

```
<div class="modalbox">
    <div class="modalbox-header">
        <h2 class="normal">Title</h2>
        <div class="modal_close">&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal_content">
        <p>Text goes here</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I make it responsive? Thanks in advance!

Comment: give it width in % not in px ;)

Comment: It doesn't seem to help. The box wont be centered then.

Comment: If margin: auto don't works. Try left, for example if width is 60%, left = (100 - 60)/2 = 20%. In the end - left:20%

Comment: Changing with to % and adding margin:auto solved the problem. Thanks a lot @morvy :-)

Comment: I think morvy need to write answer and hskrijelj need to mark it as correct, otherwise it looks like first answer is right one.

Answer (score 0):

When giving Width in CSS, add max-width: ... that will do the trick !

Like so :

```
div.modalbox {
    background: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding : 10px;
    max-width: 400px;
    display : none;
    position : absolute;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution involves little bit of hacking a library file itself. First we limit the width of container to never go out of screen

```
div.modalbox {
    max-width: 94%;
    display : none;
}
```

Now in jquery.leanModal.js file find a place where modal element is positioned on screen (line 42) and change it like this

```
$(modal_id).css({           
    'display' : 'block',
    'position' : 'fixed',
    'opacity' : 0,
    'z-index': 11000,
    //'left' : 50 + '%',
    'left' : ($(window).width() - modal_width)/2 + "px",  //<--this was margin-left before
    'top' : o.top + "px"
});
```

And now it is responsive. And container will still use content width on bigger screens.

Additionally, if you want to follow popup behavior by resizing browser width without refreshing page, add this code in library file somewhere above e.preventDefault(); (line ~55)

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    $(modal_id).css({ 
        'left' : ($(window).width() - $(modal_id).outerWidth())/2 + "px"
    });
});
```